# TortoiseSVN switching, branching and working on branching

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging, svn-switch

*I am asking here which may be some basic stuff, but still want to go on with my post in pursue of learning.*

I got into SVN recently and some questions are bugging my mind. I have got a repository which has a */trunk* where all the current development process is taking place. I have created a branch in repo with the contents of trunk and updated my branch folder (on my local machine), so that all the contents from repository branch are copied to my local branch. I have used the `svn switch` option to switch from trunk to branch on my local machine.

Can some one answer the following questions:

1. After working on branch I need to `svn update` my local branch to repo branch so that the changes take place in repo right?
2. How can I find the changes which I have made to my local branch? Let me say for example the URL for the repo where the main dev is taking place (i.e */trunk*) is accessible by `dev.mobile42.com` and I update my local branch to repo branch, how can I make the repo branch to reflect my changes with the same URL `dev.mobile42.com`, is it enough to do the switch on my local machine so that it reflects the changes or am I wrong here. Some how I need to see the results for which I have worked on my branch. How can I do this!

P.S since Im working on web dev it is necessary to do through tests before I merge my branch in trunk.

Comment: You should read the SVNBook. At least the basics: see the fundamental concepts behind SVN: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html

Your questions are quite obscure since as far as I see you confuse 'branch' and working copy terms as well as 'commit' and 'update'.

Comment: +1 to @bahrep. You should also read the first chapter of TortoiseSVN's help. Right-click on any folder, choose TortoiseSVN, then Help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, but this will be effective only if other modifications were made on your branch, by other people, for instance.
2. You're missing some steps here. To trunk reflect the branch changes, you'll have to **Reintegrate The Branch** into the trunk, and then commit the trunk.

Before reintegration, it's recommended that you **Merge A Range Of Revisions** from trunk into your branch, and then test your branch with the trunk modifications.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must grok [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/)
2. Check the manual

Now you don't see and understand fundamental things

- There are not such thing in Subversion, as "Local Branches". The are *only* **Repository** and one or more (local for you) **Working Copies**, which are slices of some point in history of some subtree of repository
- Work cycle in SVN is "checkout-edit-commit-edit-commit..." with updates in the middle for obtaining (possible) third-party parallel changes on the same codebase - for **any** Working Copy (linked to trunk/branch/whatever): i.e changes in WC must be stored in Repo (in the *relevant part* of) with commit
- Data transmitted (copied) between subtrees with merges
- For httpd-served repository any part of repository is accessible with `<some URL>` using ordinary browser, but none of active content will be active inside repository, you have to have build-deploy stage. And in this case it's task of of your builder - *From* and *To* and *What* to deploy